# algorithm to name files with no probability of repetition

Tags: php

Can someone suggest a complex algorithm in php to name files that would be uploaded so that it never repeats? i wonder how youtube which has millions of videos does it??

Right now i use an random number and get its 16 character sha1 hash and name the file with that name but i'm pretty sure it will eventually repeat and generate an error as file will not be able to save in the file system.

something like:

```
$name = sha1(substr(sha1(md5($randomnumber)),0,10));
```

somebody once told me that its impossible to break the hash generated by this code or at least it'll take 100 years to break it.

Comment: use a GUID..............

Comment: @diEcho do u mean i generate a hash with this code using the timestamp? what about in the case when two users upload a file at exactly the same time? i know thats not very likely but it has a possibility.

Comment: @MitchWheat i'm nt following you exactly. please elaborate.

Comment: @NikhilVerma there may be a mili second difference between both uploading. Timestamp is always unique in any case. ( except very rare )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do below with proper methods.

- First slice its extension and filename
- Now Trim the filename
- Change multiple Space into single space
- Replace special character and whitespace into to `_`
- Prefix with current timestamp using  [`strtotime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and salt using `md5(uniqid(rand(), true))` separated by `_` (Thanks to @Sudhir )
- Suffix with a special signature using [`str_pad`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) and limit the text length of a file
- Now again add extension and formatted file name

hope it make sense.

Thanks

Comment: yes it does make sense. only thing, how do i add a special signature using str_pad? i know this is out of the scope of this question but if u can suggest something? and also do u think the algorithm u explained has a zero probability of repeating?

Comment: @NikhilVerma yes that is Zero repeating. and Please read the manual of `str_pad` ( i have given the link too ). It would be better if you try and find by yourself.

Comment: i up voted yours but it somehow appeared as 0 still. i am sorry.

Comment: @NikhilVerma Its okay. chalta hai yaar. :)

Comment: @NikhilVerma I am An Indian yaar. See my profile : http://stackoverflow.com/users/155861/diecho

Comment: just tested it, i think it will be very hard to crack and wil be 100% unique.. thanks man..

Comment: it takes a couple of seconds on a webserver to generate this. i have broken up evrything into variables to perform every step. do u think i should do it otherwise? and how can i make it faster? As this is taking a couple of seconds just to genrate name wonder what will happen when i will try to upload a file along with this.

Comment: No it will not take too much time . and a fraction of seconds does not affect your complete website. as file uploading always take time.

Answer (score 4):

you could do:

```
$uniq = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
```

You could also apped user id of users uploading the file, like:

```
$uniq = $user_id_of_uploader."_".md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
```

Comment: are u sure this will never clash or repeat? and do u have any idea what these big firms like youtube or facebook might use while generating filenames?

Comment: @NikhilVerma well, the uniqid should not clash at most cases , but if you want to be more confirm about it, then you could add extra values like one added in answer (user_id of file uploaded appended)

Comment: thanks man, appending unique id of the user seems like a good idea.

Comment: @Sudhir I have used you code in my answer too. thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Generate a GUID (sometimes called UUID) using a pre-existing implementation. GUIDs are unique per computer, timestamp, GUID generated during that timestamp and so on, so they will never repeat.

If making a GUID isn't available, using sha1 on the entire input and using the entire output of it is second best.

Answer (score 1):

```
$name = 'filename'.$user_id(if_available).md5(microtime(true)).'extension';
```

Try to remove special characters and white spaces from the file name.

**If you are saving name in database then a recursive function can be helpful.**

Answer (score 0):

I usually just generate a string for the filename (implementation is not incredibly important), then check if a file already exists with that name. If so, append a counter to it. If you somehow have a lot of files with the same base filename, this could be inefficient, but assuming your string is unique enough, it shouldn't happen very often. There's also the overhead of checking that the file exists.

```
$base_name = generate_some_random_string(); // use whatever method you like
$extension = '.jpg'; // Change as necessary
$file_name = $base_name . $extension;
$i = 0;
while (file_exists($file_name)) {
    $file_name = $base_name . $i++ . $extension;
}
/* insert code to save the file as $file_name */
```